# R: Record Linkage in R

Tags: r, match, data-manipulation, record-linkage

Has anyone tried to do record linkage in R before?

I am following these tutorials over here:

https://rdrr.io/cran/fastLink/man/fastLink.html

https://github.com/kosukeimai/fastLink

```
library(fastLink)

fl.out <- fastLink(dfA, dfB,
varnames = c("firstname", "lastname", "streetname", "birthyear"),
n.cores = 1)
```

The `fl.out` object is created. From here, it is unclear to determine which records were determined as matches, and how "certain" these matches were.

The following line is supposed to display the matches:

```
fl.out$matches
```

But is there an easier way to see all the records that matched and the "strength of these matches"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the option `return.df = TRUE` to return the objects `dfA.match` and `dfB.match` rather than just the indices.

```
fl.out <- fastLink(dfA, dfB,
                   varnames = c("firstname", "lastname", "streetname", "birthyear"),
                   n.cores = 1, 
                   return.df = TRUE)
```

Another option is to define matched datasets with the objects `inds.a` and `inds.b`.

```
fl.out <- fastLink(dfA, dfB,
                   varnames = c("firstname", "lastname", "streetname", "birthyear"),
                   n.cores = 1)

matchedA <- dfA[fl.out$matches$inds.a, ]
matchedB <- dfB[fl.out$matches$inds.b, ]
```

The "strength of the matches" can be seen in the posterior probabilities of the match, which is output in the object `fl.out$posterior`.